# Endianness: le32_to_cpu in User Space

Tags: linux, kernel, endianness

I am writing a User Space mapped application using `/dev/mem`. Is there some function in the Linux kernel that does the equivalent of `le32_to_cpu` from user space ?

Is there an alternate method to achieve this ?

RRS

P.S: I am cross-compiling this application for an embedded board (Xilinx Microblaze running Linux)

Comment: What does `le32_to_cpu` do? Maybe same as `htons` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `#include <endian.h>` and the macro `le32toh()` from this header.

Comment: I accept the answer, although it looks like the compiler does not support le32toh. I will have to think of a better way.

Comment: `le32toh()` is fairly standard, and if your environment doesn't include it, it's trivial to write.  `endian.h` should at least define `BIG_ENDIAN` or `LITTLE_ENDIAN` so you can choose when `le32toh()` needs to actually do something.